# How to use an IF statement to pull cells only with >= XXXX

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to look at the number of users who are on screens larger than 1400. I have my Excel sheet, and tried doing an IF statement, but because of the "x" in the middle, it's not working properly and is instead just pulling all of the cells, even the ones with screen sizes less than 1400. I've attached my formula and data example for reference. I've also tried putting a space after the fourth integer to separate things that way, but that also goofs things up since there are some screen sizes with only three numbers.

This is my formula:
=IF(A2>=1400,A2,"No")

[image]

Comment: you want this in google sheets ?

Comment: I'm on Excel, I threw the Google Sheets tag on just for relevance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in Column A are strings.  A string will always be larger than a number to Excel.  You need to parse the string to pull the first number:

```
=IF(--LEFT(A2,SEARCH("x",A2&"x")-1)>1400,A2,"No")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Would you mind just breaking the formula down a bit? I know the LEFT tells Excel to look for the leftmost part of the cell, but what does the -1 mean, why are there 2 "x"'s, etc.? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: SEARCH returns the first position of the value searching for.  We use this position to limit the left.  the `--` turns the string into a number so we can properly compare the inequality.  The second `x` is to ensure no errors in case it was written without an `x`

Comment: @ScottCraner - The `VALUE(...)` function would be clearer than `--`.

Comment: @Enigmativity it is perfectly clear to me and a lot less typing.

Comment: @ScottCraner - It's not perfectly clear to the OP and possibly not for future readers.