# How can I pull any cells with a value greater than a number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I asked a similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587439/how-to-use-an-if-statement-to-pull-cells-only-with-xxxx) but I realized the >=1400 can be either before or after my "x".

I'm trying to look at the number of users who are on screens larger than 1400. I have my Excel sheet, and tried doing an IF statement, but because of the "x" in the middle, it's not working properly and is instead just pulling all of the cells, even the ones with screen sizes less than 1400. I want to be able to pull all cells with Screen Resolution values larger than 1400 on either the first or second number.

All of the numbers highlighted in yellow would be the ones pulled.

I've tried doing slight variations of the =IF(--LEFT(A2,SEARCH("x",A2&"x")-1)>1400,A2,"No") but I can't find the right format to narrate that I want the formula to look at both numbers on either side of the "x".

[image]

Comment: What does "pull" mean?

Comment: Just I want my formula to only grab the cells in column A if they match my criteria to pull that information to column C

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? Office365 will easier your work.

Comment: I'm on Office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(VALUE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("X",A2)-1))>=1400,VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("X",A2)))>=1400),A2,"No"),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with array formula:

```
=IF(OR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"x","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[1 or 2]")>1400),A2,"No")
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked too! That is interesting - I've never seen a formula where you have to hit cntrl + shift + enter to make it work (without doing that, this formula only pulled the cells with the >=1400 as the first number). That's really cool, what does the cntrl + shift + enter do?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Excel365` then try below formula.

```
=FILTER(A2:A10,(--TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10,"x",REPT(" ",100)),100))>=1400)+(--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10,"x",REPT(" ",100)),100))>=1400))
```

Or use-

```
=FILTER(A2:A10,(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10,"x","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")>=1400)+(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10,"x","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[2]")>=1400))
```

[image]

Comment: `FilterXML()` formula will give you best performance.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a complicated formula, you could just split the data up.

Create two new columns next to column A. Then use text to columns and delimit on the “x”.

In the E column use a simple formula of

```
IF(OR(B2>=1400,C2>=1400),”True”,”False”)
```